# What makes the difference between declaring variable = 0 and leaving variable by itself?

Tags: c

I was looking through 'while loop' and figured that the result was different when I declared variables = 0 and when I did not in the loop.

I am not sure why it makes different result...

Here`s example!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int even=0;
    int total=0;

    do{
        total+=even;
        even+=2;
    }while(even<=100);

    printf("total : %d", total);

    return 0;

}
```

result
**total : 2550**

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main(){

    int even;
    int total;

    do{
        total+=even;
        even+=2;
    }while(even<=100);

    printf("total : %d", total);

    return 0;

}
```

result
**total:2551**

Comment: Undefined behavior in the second case.

Comment: Because... you did not assign a value. In the second case, what do you think the value of `even` and `total` are before you sum them?

Answer (score 0):

The following is undefined behaviour:

```c
int even;
int total;
total += even;
```

Before reading from a variable with automatic storage duration, you must initialize it or assign to it.